# How to create dropdownlist from reference table in mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created MVC project and use EF to get data,

Here is the **table stucture for tblRecStatus**

```
RecStatusId     int
RecStatusName   nvarchar(20)
RecStatusDecr   nvarchar(100)
CreateOn        datetime
CreateBy        int
ModifyOn        datetime
ModifyBy        int
```

And here is the **table stucture for tblLogType**

```
LogTypeId       int
LogTypeCode     nvarchar(2)
LogTypeName     nvarchar(20)
LogTypeDecr     nvarchar(100)
RecStatusId     int
CreateOn        datetime
CreateBy        int
ModifyOn        datetime
ModifyBy        int
```

tblLogType.RecStatusId have foreign key to tblRecStatus.RecStatusId

The **DataAccess for LogTypeDA** :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace i_insurance.DataAccess
{
    public class LogTypeDA : BaseDA
    {
        public List<tblLogType> GetAll()
        {
            return (from tblLogType o in this.DataContext.tblLogTypes
                    select o).ToList();
        }

        public tblLogType GetById(int Id)
        {
            return (from tblLogType o in this.DataContext.tblLogTypes
                    where o.LogTypeId == Id
                    select o).SingleOrDefault();
        }


        public void Insert(tblLogType tblLogType)
        {
            try
            {
                this.DataContext.tblLogTypes.Add(tblLogType);
                this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

        public void Delete(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                tblLogType tblLogTypeOnDb = (from tblLogType o in this.DataContext.tblLogTypes
                                     where o.LogTypeId == Id
                                     select o).SingleOrDefault();

                this.DataContext.tblLogTypes.Remove(tblLogTypeOnDb);
                this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }


        public void Update(tblLogType tblLogType)
        {
            try
            {
                tblLogType tblLogTypeOnDb = (from tblLogType o in this.DataContext.tblLogTypes
                                             where o.LogTypeId == tblLogType.LogTypeId
                                     select o).SingleOrDefault();

                tblLogTypeOnDb.LogTypeCode = tblLogType.LogTypeCode;
                tblLogTypeOnDb.LogTypeName = tblLogType.LogTypeName;
                tblLogTypeOnDb.LogTypeDecr = tblLogType.LogTypeDecr;
                tblLogTypeOnDb.RecStatusId = tblLogType.RecStatusId;
                tblLogTypeOnDb.ModifyOn = tblLogType.ModifyOn;
                tblLogTypeOnDb.ModifyBy = tblLogType.ModifyBy;

                this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The **Model for this LogTypeModel** :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;
using i_insurance.DataAccess;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace i_insurance.Models
{
    public class LogTypeModel
    {

        public class LogType
        {
            [Key]
            public int LogTypeId { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Log Type Code is required.")]
            [Display(Name = "Log Type Code")]
            [MaxLength(2)]
            public string LogTypeCode { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Log Type Name is required.")]
            [Display(Name = "Log Type Name")]
            [MaxLength(20)]
            public string LogTypeName { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Log Type Description")]
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string LogTypeDecr { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Record Status")]
            public int? RecStatusId { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public DateTime? CreateOn { get; set; }

            public int? CreateBy { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public DateTime? ModifyOn { get; set; }

            public int? ModifyBy { get; set; }

            // additional column, example column from other table
            public string RecStatusName { get; set; }
            public string CreateByUserName { get; set; }
            public string ModifyByUserName { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RecordStatusList { get; set; }

        }

        public LogTypeModel()
        {
            this.LogTypeList = new List<LogType>();
        }

        public List<LogType> LogTypeList { get; set; }




    }


}
```

Here is the **Controller LogTypeController** :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using i_insurance.Models;
using i_insurance.DataAccess;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using i_insurance.Filters;
using i_insurance;



namespace i_insurance.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class LogTypeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Log/




        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult LogTypeIndex()
        {
            LogTypeDA LogTypeDA = new LogTypeDA();
            List<tblLogType> lsTblLogType;

            lsTblLogType = LogTypeDA.GetAll();
            LogTypeModel model = new LogTypeModel();

            RecStatusDA RecStatusDA = new RecStatusDA();

            foreach (tblLogType o in lsTblLogType)
            {
                LogTypeModel.LogType LogType = new LogTypeModel.LogType();

                LogType.LogTypeId = o.LogTypeId;
                LogType.LogTypeCode = o.LogTypeCode;
                LogType.LogTypeName = o.LogTypeName;
                LogType.LogTypeDecr = o.LogTypeDecr;
                LogType.RecStatusId = o.RecStatusId;
                LogType.CreateOn = o.CreateOn;
                LogType.CreateBy = o.CreateBy;
                LogType.ModifyOn = o.ModifyOn;
                LogType.ModifyBy = o.ModifyBy;

                //additional column
                LogType.RecStatusName = o.tblRecStatu.RecStatusName;
                LogType.CreateByUserName = o.UserProfile.UserName;
                LogType.ModifyByUserName = o.UserProfile1.UserName;

                model.LogTypeList.Add(LogType);
            }

            return View(model);
        }




        //[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogTypeCreate()
        {
            //ViewBag.RecStatusList = new RecStatusDA().GetAll();
            //return View();
            var model = new LogTypeModel.LogType { RecordStatusList = HelperController.GetAllRecStatus() };
            return View(model);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogTypeCreate(LogTypeModel.LogType LogType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    DateTime CurrentTime = new DateTime();
                    CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;

                    LogTypeDA LogTypeDA = new LogTypeDA();
                    tblLogType tblLogType = new tblLogType();

                    tblLogType.LogTypeCode = LogType.LogTypeCode;
                    tblLogType.LogTypeName = LogType.LogTypeName;
                    tblLogType.LogTypeDecr = LogType.LogTypeDecr;
                    tblLogType.RecStatusId = LogType.RecStatusId;
                    tblLogType.CreateOn = CurrentTime;
                    tblLogType.CreateBy = WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
                    tblLogType.ModifyOn = CurrentTime;
                    tblLogType.ModifyBy = WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

                    LogTypeDA.Insert(tblLogType);
                    return RedirectToAction("LogTypeIndex");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return View(LogType);
        }


        // GET: /Log/LogTypeDelete/5
        public ActionResult LogTypeDelete(int Id, bool? saveChangesError)
        {
            if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.";
            }

            LogTypeDA LogTypeDA = new LogTypeDA();
            tblLogType tblLogType = new tblLogType();
            tblLogType = LogTypeDA.GetById(Id);

            LogTypeModel.LogType model = new LogTypeModel.LogType();
            model.LogTypeCode = tblLogType.LogTypeCode;
            model.LogTypeName = tblLogType.LogTypeName;
            model.LogTypeDecr = tblLogType.LogTypeDecr;


            return View(model);
        }


        // POST: /Log/LogTypeDelete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("LogTypeDelete")]
        public ActionResult LogTypeDelete(int Id)
        {
            LogTypeDA LogTypeDA = new LogTypeDA();
            LogTypeDA.Delete(Id);

            return RedirectToAction("LogTypeIndex");
        }


        public ActionResult LogTypeRead(int Id)
        {
            LogTypeDA LogTypeDA = new LogTypeDA();
            tblLogType tblLogType = LogTypeDA.GetById(Id);

            LogTypeModel.LogType model = new LogTypeModel.LogType();

            model.LogTypeId = tblLogType.LogTypeId;
            model.LogTypeCode = tblLogType.LogTypeCode;
            model.LogTypeName = tblLogType.LogTypeName;
            model.LogTypeDecr = tblLogType.LogTypeDecr;
            model.RecStatusId = tblLogType.RecStatusId;
            model.CreateOn = tblLogType.CreateOn;
            model.CreateBy = tblLogType.CreateBy;
            model.ModifyOn = tblLogType.ModifyOn;
            model.ModifyBy = tblLogType.ModifyBy;

            //for additional column
            model.RecStatusName = tblLogType.tblRecStatu.RecStatusName;
            model.CreateByUserName = tblLogType.UserProfile.UserName;
            model.ModifyByUserName = tblLogType.UserProfile1.UserName;


            return View(model);

        }

        // GET: /Log/LogTypeUpdate/5
        public ActionResult LogTypeUpdate(int Id)
        {
            LogTypeDA LogTypeDA = new LogTypeDA();
            tblLogType tblLogType = new tblLogType();
            tblLogType = LogTypeDA.GetById(Id);

            LogTypeModel.LogType model = new LogTypeModel.LogType();

            model.LogTypeId = Id;
            model.LogTypeCode = tblLogType.LogTypeCode;
            model.LogTypeName = tblLogType.LogTypeName;
            model.LogTypeDecr = tblLogType.LogTypeDecr;
            model.RecStatusId = tblLogType.RecStatusId;

            // for dropdownlist value
            //ViewBag.RecStatusList = new RecStatusDA().GetAll();
            model.RecordStatusList = HelperController.GetAllRecStatus();

            return View(model);

        }


        // POST: /Log/LogType/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogTypeUpdate(LogTypeModel.LogType LogType)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    LogTypeDA LogTypeDA = new LogTypeDA();
                    tblLogType tblLogType = new tblLogType();

                    DateTime CurrentDateTime = new DateTime();
                    CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;


                    tblLogType.LogTypeId = LogType.LogTypeId;
                    tblLogType.LogTypeCode = LogType.LogTypeCode;
                    tblLogType.LogTypeName = LogType.LogTypeName;
                    tblLogType.LogTypeDecr = LogType.LogTypeDecr;
                    tblLogType.RecStatusId = LogType.RecStatusId;
                    tblLogType.ModifyOn = CurrentDateTime;
                    tblLogType.ModifyBy = WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

                    LogTypeDA.Update(tblLogType);
                    return RedirectToAction("LogTypeIndex");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(LogType);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **general class function in controller** :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using i_insurance.Models;
using i_insurance.DataAccess;
using System.Data;

namespace i_insurance
{
    public class HelperController : Controller
    {

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllRecStatus()
        {
            var recStatusDA = new RecStatusDA();
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> slItem = from s in recStatusDA.GetAll()
                                                 select new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Text = s.RecStatusName,
                                                     Value = s.RecStatusId.ToString()
                                                 };

            return slItem;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the **View LogTypeCreate.cshtml** code to create new LogType data:

```
@model i_insurance.Models.LogTypeModel.LogType

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New Log Type";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log Type</legend>

        <br />
        <br />

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogTypeCode)</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogTypeCode)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogTypeCode)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogTypeName)</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogTypeName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogTypeName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogTypeDecr)</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogTypeDecr)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogTypeDecr)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecStatusId)</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.RecStatusId, new SelectList(ViewBag.RecStatusList,"RecStatusId","RecStatusName"))*@
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecStatusId, Model.RecordStatusList)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecStatusId)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "LogTypeIndex")
</div>
```

My question how to make this mvc view support dropdownlist from reference table tblRecStatus ?

```
With 
BindText  = tblRecStatus.RecStatusName
BindValue = tblRecStatus.RecStatusId (0  = dis active, 1 = active)

Example :
Dropdownlist will contain
 - Dis Active
 - Active

if user choose Active, it will save value 1 for column tblLogType.RecStatusId
```

Thank You.

I already test solution from **@Motomoto Pink**, and it worked for dropdownlist 
and still have issue when i try to create new data or update data logType with leave all field blank

Here is the error code :

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'RecStatusId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

**Source Error** :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecStatusId, Model.RecordStatusList)

Source File: d:\Projects\VS2012\Website\i_insurance\i_insurance\Views\LogType\LogTypeUpdate.cshtml    Line: 48
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'RecStatusId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.GetSelectData(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String name) +355
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +142
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList) +60
   ASP._Page_Views_LogType_LogTypeUpdate_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Projects\VS2012\Website\i_insurance\i_insurance\Views\LogType\LogTypeUpdate.cshtml:48
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +103
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9634212
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create **DataAccess** for **tblRecStatus** table to get all data from tblRecStatus (Maybe you already have it)

```
public class RecStatusDA : BaseDA
{
    public List<tblRecStatus> GetAll()
    {
       return (from tblRecStatus s in this.DataContext.tblRecStatus
                    select s).ToList();
    }
}
```

Next, add one more properties into **LogTypeModel.LogType** class for manage data from tblRecStatus

```
namespace i_insurance.Models
{
    public class LogTypeModel
    {
        public class LogType
        {
         ...
         public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList { get; set; }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

In the Controller, **LogTypeController**, you have to bind data to DropDownList at method LogTypeCreate (which is not HttpPost method), see the code below:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllRecStatus()
{
    var recStatusDA = new RecStatusDA();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> slItem = from s in recStatusDA.GetAll()
                                            select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Selected = s.RecStatusId.ToString() == "default value you want to set"
                                                Text = s.RecStatusName,
                                                Value = s.RecStatusId.ToString()
                                            };
    return slItem;
}

public ActionResult LogTypeCreate()
{
    var model = new LogTypeModel.LogType { selectList = GetAllRecStatus() };
    return View(model);
}
```

In the View **LogTypeCreate.cshtml**, define the DropDownList

```
<tr>
   <td>Status</td>
   <td>:</td>
   <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecStatusId, Model.selectList)
   </td>
</tr>
```

Final, see in the **LogTypeCreate (HttpPost method)**, you could set selected ResStatusId to tblLogType.RecStatusId

```
tblLogType.RecStatusId = LogType.RecStatusId;
```

Comment: Hi Motomoto, i try something new when i create new LogType in page LogTypeCreate.cshtml and fill blank in all field then press button create this error appear in 

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecStatusId, Model.RecordStatusList)


error info :
 The ViewData item that has the key 'RecStatusId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. 

why this happen and how i can fix this one ? , thank

Comment: Could I see your new LogType to investigate this?

Comment: Yes you can, i already updated the code in my main question, and how i can set the default value for dropdownlist record status when i create new data [i want to set the active value in dropdownlist]?

Comment: Yes, you can set the default select value, see in LogTypeController code, I updaed my answer.

Comment: I alredy try to add code in my controller
Selected = s.RecStatusId.ToString()
but selected is bool property, it generate error when i add that code.
And how about the error when i submit new blank data in  @Html.DropDownListFor ?

Comment: Seems you didn't see my code clearly, the sample is `Selected = s.RecStatusId.ToString() == "default value you want to set"`. For passing empty data in DropDownList, that should be effected to post method because RecStatusId is Integer, so you have to set default as Integer value to pass.

Comment: Otherwist you can set option label to display in DropDownList at first loading: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecStatusId, Model.RecordStatusList, "-- Select Status --")`.

Comment: Great, i already test for 
 `Selected = s.RecStatusId.ToString() == "Active"`

and it work for default value in DropDownListFor.
**i also add error info when i want to create new logtype data, with blank value in all field in my question**, hope you can tell me where is the root cause for this issue

Comment: Do you still have code for setting **ViewBag.RecStatusList** somewhere in you controller? If that so, please remove it out.

Comment: It already remark as comment
`//ViewBag.RecStatusList = new RecStatusDA().GetAll();`

Comment: Oh I just noticed that the problem happenned on **LogTypeUpdate.cshtml**, not the file we talked about before, so we have to start agaian with posting LogTypeUpdate.cshtml. I think you should create new question to avoid confuse.

Comment: Ok bro, i will create new question again for this issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify a collection in your model which contains all the elements of the drop down list.

```
prop List<TblRecStatus> StatusList {get; set;}
```

Then in your view just do this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusList, new SelectList(StatusList, "StatusID", "StatusName"))
```

Comment: Hi Gjohn, i already updated my LogTypeModel, and updated my view base on your suggestion, but i get this error :

Error 1 The name 'StatusList' does not exist in the current context 

in VS indicator it error in this code:
new SelectList(StatusList,

StatusList seem not available, is there other requirement for this ?